# WPF Datagrid - Binding

Tags: wpf, binding

Could you please help with the binding.

I have four fields that are bound to a datagrid source using XAML binding.
string field1, field2, field3
bool field4

I need to change the color of field3 to red based on value in field4 (which is a bool).

Comment: You'll probably want to use a `DataTrigger` on the `DataGridCellTemplate`. Should be able to find plenty of information online, or if you included your XAML I'm sure someone would help you out with the exact syntax you'd need. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter to convert the `boolean` into a `SolidColorBrush`.  A value converter does what its name implies: It converts one value into another.  In your case, you want to convert a `boolean` to a `SolidColorBrush`, depending on what the `boolean` is.

Here's a short example on how to make a value converter and how to use it.  It must implement the `IValueConvert` interface, located in `System.Windows.Data`.  Usually, you only need to fully implement the `Convert` method.

```
class BooleanToBrush : IValueConverter
{
    Brush solidRed = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    Brush empty = new SolidColorBrush();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool showRed = (bool)value;
        if (showRed)
            return solidRed;
        else
            return empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToBrush x:Key="b2b" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="{Binding someBooleanProperty, Converter={StaticResource b2b}}">
</Grid>
```

More information on value converters can be found here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html